# I want help and idea about how to draw The path of GPS in C#

Tags: c#, gps, tracking

as you can see i want to do senior project about soccer player tracking  with gps to show the path that player was using or tracking in real time

i already study about basic gps function in c#  but  I Really Have problems on how to draw paths on the map or picture that i want to use after we got the data from gps.

the hardware part are already finish but i get stuck in and idea for how to get the data from gps to draw path of player

I appreciate with any help on me  ( sorry for bad english) Thank you very much

Link of my designed project picture :

http://image.ohozaa.com/view2/weK9gVKBzGZqRxKC

Comment: Have you already started collecting data from GPS, if so, how are you storing it?

Comment: Vote to close... does not look like related to GPS or tracking... And shows not enough effort on "how can I draw line by coordinates" part. Consider editing your question to just contain code+information you have trouble with.

Comment: yes sorry i should change to   i want an idea for doing this project not just ask right away   
my bad thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just think about what you're doing.

- GPS data (from each player) is received as a sequence of points (Latitude/Longitude?).
- Convert those points to X/Y coordinates for your football field image
- Use a graphics API (such as GDI / System.Drawing ) to draw lines between subsequent points

If you're using C# you might save time and trouble by using WinForms and subclassing `Control` and painting directly to the control's surface. You'll need to store a list of all the recent points for each player (because you'll need to constantly repaint the control).

Note that the geolocation features in .NET won't help you here unless all of your football players are going to be carrying laptops strapped to their backs. You'd want small GPS trackers attached to each player along with a small radiotransmitter that sends the data. An easy way to do this is with a commodity Bluetooth GPS unit, but I don't know if Bluetooth can support that many transceivers in such a small space, or even if the signal will reach from one end of the field to another. The most expensive way is to write a phone app and have each player carry a smartphone that sends geolocation data via a 3G or Wifi connection.

Note that GPS units tend to have a usable accuracy of about 5m (maybe 2.5m on a good day), and are useless indoors. Then consider the 5 minutes it takes for them to secure a good lock in the first place (mobile phones have quick geolocation because they use assistance from mobile phone masts). Football fields aren't very big, and even with 2.5m accuracy the data isn't going to be very useful.

In real sports they don't use GPS for this reason. Instead they use higher-precision radio units and specialist transmitter/receiver units placed around the pitch. An alternative is visual tracking, but that's an immature science (Turing help you if two players or more wearing the same team colour collapse into each other).

Comment: thank you very much with your idea.
yes i want to do it with  radio Frequency but  my professor just want to do it this way ....  -- -- too bad

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the picture you provided I'd say something like this is feasible with a WPF application using the Canvas control and the Line class. You'd have to convert your GPS data to (x,y)-coordinates where the origin is located at the upper left corner of the soccer field. Then you could connect subsequent points using line segments.